# Java RMI: Implement a time out in the client code

Tags: java, timeout, rmi

I have a Java RMI system. The situation is typical: the client invokes a method of the server.
The client has an internal timer, so if the server doesn't finish in due time (the time is specified in the client), then the client must do something else.

So, the client must wait for the server to finish its job for a specific time and in case the server didn't finish do something else (it doesn't matter what). `How can I do this?`

I don't care about connection timeouts and so on, assume that the server and client are connected through RMI and everything it's fine, only that the server's job can be computationally intensive and can require some time.

thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140679/is-it-possible-to-interrupt-a-java-rmi-call/5140805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the RMI call on another thread. Have the originating thread wait a certain length of time for a response from the RMI-calling thread.

Alternatively, have the server RMI thread delegate the task to a worker thread. Return to the caller if the worker thread doesn't respond sufficiently quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you want operations to timeout in Java, you are talking about one or two synchronous/asynchronous conversion layers. I've never done this with RMI, but I imagine you do something similar. Perhaps asking the participants of this discussion: ( [Asynchronous Java RMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902393/asynchronous-java-rmi) ) will be useful. Based on the points made in ( [Spring Async RMI Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250716/spring-async-rmi-call) ), I would say you need to do the following:

1. Call the RMI service using separate thread(s); consider using executor service.
2. Expose this with a wrapper that calls through to the executor service and blocks for a finite amount of time for results; consider using Futures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the undocumented property called (I think) sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout at each client JVM. Value in milliseconds.